# How to access embedded Resources without the use of "My" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, resources, codedom

I added some resources in my codedom project but I have no Idea how to access the resources? the "My" Keyword is not available and it doesn't work:

```
My.Resources.blabla.ToString
```

**How can I access my resources without the using of "My" keyword?**
TY

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for where you are trying to use the statement?

Comment: I added a resource with the codedom EmbeddedResources method and the codedom compiled an exe for me - i want to be able to access that embedded resource in my exe but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

With anything in the `My` namespace, you can right-click a term (such as `blabla`) and select *Go to Definition*.  It will either show you the code behind the `My` namespace, or direct you to the object reference which will show the full class name.

In your case, you can rewrite this namespace to suit your purpose.

```
Namespace My.Resources

    '''<summary>
    '''  A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    '''</summary>
    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0"), _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(), _
     Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute()> _
    Friend Module Resources

        Private resourceMan As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager

        Private resourceCulture As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo

        '''<summary>
        '''  Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        '''</summary>
        <Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
        Friend ReadOnly Property ResourceManager() As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager
            Get
                If Object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, Nothing) Then
                    Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("WindowsApplication1.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                    resourceMan = temp
                End If
                Return resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        '''  Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        '''  resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        '''</summary>
        <Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
        Friend Property Culture() As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo
            Get
                Return resourceCulture
            End Get
            Set(value As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
                resourceCulture = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<summary>
        '''  Looks up a localized string similar to Blah.
        '''</summary>
        Friend ReadOnly Property String1() As String
            Get
                Return ResourceManager.GetString("String1", resourceCulture)
            End Get
        End Property
    End Module
End Namespace
```